# Why this PHP comparison it wont return True

Tags: php, ctf

Why this PHP comparison it wont return True and is there a way i can make it return true ?

```
<?php

highlight_file(__FILE__);
error_reporting(0);
$first = $_GET['first_flag'];

echo ' :: ' . md5($first);
echo ' :: ' . $first ."<br/>";

if($first == md5($first)){
    echo "True";
}else {
    echo "False";
}


?>
```

when i put QNKCDZO it returns :

> :: 0e830400451993494058024219903391 :: QNKCDZO
>   False

Comment: How can a string be equal to an md5 hash of itself?

Comment: ```md5``` generates a hash from the string ```$first```. So it never be equal.

Comment: It is CTF ..that is the trick i could not figure

Comment: can you show whats being asked of you? your code is impossible there is no md5 string which hashes to the same string

Comment: `if (true || $first == md5($first)){` your welcome ;p

Comment: [`0e215962017`](https://3v4l.org/IsVRS)

Comment: @iainn that should be in an awnser

Comment: 0e215962017 yesss that was right WTF. How could u find it ?

Comment: Is there a list or something

Answer (score 7):

The key is to notice that the comparison is done using `==`, which opens up options involving type juggling.

Strings in the format `1e2` (where 1 and 2 are numbers of any size) are interpreted as [scientific-notation floating point values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) by PHP. Because any value in the form `0e...` evaluates to zero (zero to any power still equals zero), the next step is to find a number `X` for which the md5 hash of `0eX` is of the same form.

The MD5 hash of `0e215962017` is **0e291242476940776845150308577824**, note that every character other than the initial `0e` is numeric.

So when comparing the values (loosely, using `==`), both evaluate to zero.

Credit to https://github.com/bl4de/ctf/blob/master/2017/HackDatKiwi_CTF_2017/md5games1/md5games1.md , which had done the (much harder) work of actually finding the number.